# Sending a message to all open windows/tabs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cross-window-scripting

I hear HTML5 has `window.postMessage()`, but it seems to require having a handle on the window (or tab, throughout this question) you're posting the message to.  What if I want to broadcast to all open windows?  Is this possible?

(What I'm trying to do is warn other windows without any server round-trips when a user does something in one window that affects the others, so that they can update their content.  However, while some windows may be opened from existing ones--allowing me to intercept and store references to them--some fresh windows may be opened manually by the user and then a bookmark selected or URL typed in.  In this case there doesn't seem to be a way to intercept and store references.)

Comment: Depending on your use-case, Comet (or other similar "HyBi" mecanism) might be a better choice; for example if you want the notification to be cross-browser (i.e. the user has opened IE and Firefox, it makes a change in IE, and expects Firefox to be notified). Also, I don't know exactly how all browsers work (there might be configurable options that changes their default behavior, such as the -no-remote command line argument for Firefox) but even for the same browser, all windows might not be able to communicate without Comet-style/server-driven communications.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a server-side fallback...I just wanted it to feel a bit snappier by being more efficient when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to broadcast a message to *other websites* (just your own), [`BroadcastChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) is made for this purpose.

```js
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('myChannel');
channel.postMessage('myMessage');
channel.addEventListener('message', m => {
    console.log('Received message from other document', m);
});
```

Answer (score 26):

I wrote a library to do just this: **[intercom.js](https://github.com/diy/intercom.js)** (for the same reasons you outlined).

We're currently using it to broadcast notifications to all windows, so only one window needs to maintain a socket connection to the server. As some others suggested, it uses the localStorage API.

**Usage is really simple:**

```
var intercom = Intercom.getInstance();

$('a').on('click', function() {
     intercom.emit('notice', {message: 'Something just happened!');
});
```

To catch the message,

```
intercom.on('notice', function(notice) {
    console.log(notice.message);
});
```

The interface is designed to mimic [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Comment: This looks pretty cool. Dumb question, but does this work between different domains? I wouldn't expect the `Storage` events to work across windows in different domains since they'll have their own `localStorage`. I know I could test it out, but I just thought I'd ask

Comment: It has to be on the same domain :/ If you *really* wanted to get crazy you could probably get crazy with iframes and postMessage + Intercom to get something cross-domain working.

Comment: Would this work effectively as a fallback for shared web workers? I'm trying to set up a webworker whose data is shared between tabs, not unlike your binding for socket.io except it's communicating with the worker instead of a server. If the tab with the worker is closed it should be relaunched on a different tab.

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't be possible :)

Comment: two disadvantages - doesn't work for offline webapps, may achieve high delays

Comment: @Lapsio You can also use `postMessage` to send messages between offline web apps on different domains. [sysend.js](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js) does this using iframes, for example.

Answer (score 21):

IMO this is not possible using the postMessage. How about using <s>sessionStorage</s>localStorage? Writing to it should generate a storage event that should be propagated to all windows sharing the same session storage.

Comment: Or cookies (as long as they're in the same domain)

Comment: cookies could also be a solution, but the advantage of storage is that it generates events when performing operations on it. When using cookies you would have to check every X seconds (setInterval) for new cookies and another problem would be when to remove the cookie.

Comment: The thing is, as I understand the spec ( http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-event ) correctly, the event should be fired in both cases (sessionStorage and localStorage). If Firefox doesn't fire the event, IMO this is a bug.

Comment: Nope, this it isn't a bug. According to the specs each document has it's own sessionStorage object, only the localStorage object is shared over all documents of the same origin. Therefore a storage event fired by the sessionStorage of Window A won't be heard by listeners, who are observing the sessionStorage of window B.

Comment: I also use local storage for this purpose. keep in mind that local storage fires even on removal of key. so its best to check event.newvalue since its null on removal.