# Communication between browser tabs/windows using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

What's the most reliable way to have JavaScript communicate between tabs/windows of the same browser? For example, when Tab 2 starts audio playback, Tab 1 somehow knows about this and can pause its player.

I'm building a site with a music player... so at the moment if you open two tabs to the site, you could start music on both.
This is obviously bad, so I'm trying to find a solution.

Comment: Auto-playing the audio is bad no matter what.  Why not just let the users click a "play" button, and manually pause the other tab if they hit this situation?

Comment: There's no autoplay. But it would be nice if the user didn't have to manually pause the other tab. Youtube does this for example (with flash)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125823/how-is-it-possible-to-share-single-js-resource-between-browser-tabs/19165781#19165781

Comment: There are other options, like shared webworkers and localstore storage event...

Comment: See [this library](https://github.com/ScarletsFiction/SFIntercom)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Update to a modern solution, leaving the old one below for historical reasons.

You can use Broadcast Channel API to send and receive messages
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API

```
// Connection to a broadcast channel
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('test_channel');

// Example of sending of a very simple message
// It doesn't have to be a string, it could be a JS object
bc.postMessage('This is a test message.');
```

To receive the message:

```
// A handler that only logs the event to the console:
bc.onmessage = function (ev) {
  console.log(ev);
}
```

and to close the channel:

```
// Disconnect the channel
bc.close();
```

---

THIS IS HISTORICAL OLD WAY TO DO IT, USE THE METHOD ABOVE FOR MODERN BROWSERS!

You can communicate between browser windows (and tabs too) using cookies.

Here is an example of sender and receiver:

sender.html

```
<h1>Sender</h1>

<p>Type into the text box below and watch the text 
   appear automatically in the receiver.</p>

<form name="sender">
<input type="text" name="message" size="30" value="">
<input type="reset" value="Clean">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function setCookie(value) {
    document.cookie = "cookie-msg-test=" + value + "; path=/";
    return true;
}
function updateMessage() {
    var t = document.forms['sender'].elements['message'];
    setCookie(t.value);
    setTimeout(updateMessage, 100);
}
updateMessage();
//--></script>
```

receiver.html:

```
<h1>Receiver</h1>

<p>Watch the text appear in the text box below as you type it in the sender.</p>

<form name="receiver">
<input type="text" name="message" size="30" value="" readonly disabled>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function getCookie() {
    var cname = "cookie-msg-test=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(cname) == 0) {
            return c.substring(cname.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
function updateMessage() {
    var text = getCookie();
    document.forms['receiver'].elements['message'].value = text;
    setTimeout(updateMessage, 100);
}
updateMessage();
//--></script>
```

Comment: I thought of something like this too, but was hoping for a better solution than cookies/setTimeout. This might just be the only solution however. Thx

Comment: what kind of player are you using? If it's a flash player, you can do stuff with flash that might be more elegant.

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout` - you're using `eval` by doing that. Instead, pass the function in directly with `setTimeout(updateMessage, 100)`

Comment: changed the setTimeout as per Yi suggestion.

Comment: I open sourced a project based on this answer, in case anyone is interested: https://github.com/jeremyharris/local_connection

Comment: I can see that setTimeout every 100 ms is consuming the javascript specially in Chrome when you open more than 4 browser tabs.

Comment: I would also recommend using `setInterval()`

Comment: I have issues with localStorage on IE11, see this post (i faced point# 3)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/16/bugs-in-ie8-support-for-html5-postmessage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage.aspx
 so the cockie soliution is better (for IE at least).
Also i tried to disable cockies but it still working (this is on IE 11, IE 10, IE 9).

Comment: This only works if both tabs have same host.

Comment: This is so bad answer I can't even...

Comment: Tomáš Zato, be aware the answer is from 2010 - when HTML5 was not supported by all the browsers and the share of IE6 and IE7 was pretty high. There are better solutions now.

Comment: That's now a very bad usage of cookies: 1) they are uselessly sent to server 2) `value` must be escaped when put in the cookie 3) having 2 "sender" tabs opened will be a mess 4) you are limited by cookie size 5) you are not applying Hollywood principle (heavy useless computations) 6) attacker can mess with this client-side only communication from the server side if they manage to alter cookies (=architecture is leaking). So see `BroadcastChannel` instead

Answer (score 150):

For a more modern solution check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514384/270274

Quote:

> I'm sticking to the shared local data solution mentioned in the question using `localStorage`. It seems to be the best solution in terms of reliability, performance, and browser compatibility.
>
> `localStorage` is implemented in all modern browsers.
>
> The `storage` event fires when *other* tabs makes changes to `localStorage`. This is quite handy for communication purposes.
>
> Reference:
> http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/
> http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-event

Comment: This is better than the accepted solution. This doesn't require you to check constantly for new informations, doesn't have a delay and enables you to receive all events.

Comment: I have issues with localStorage on IE11, see this post (i faced point# 3)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/16/bugs-in-ie8-support-for-html5-postmessage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage.aspx
 so the cockie soliution is better (for IE at least).
Also i tried to disable cockies but it still working (this is on IE 11).

Comment: Good demo page - http://html5demos.com/storage-events#view-source

Comment: @Anas: Link is dead. New URL: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/09/15/html5-implementation-issues-in-ie8-and-later/

Comment: This solve a lot of issues (are is wider implemented than BroadcastChannel), but be careful that you will have some surprises if user opens 2 "sender" tabs in the same browser: having 1 common communication channel might raise up some surprises

Answer (score 16):

I don't think you need cookies. Each document's JavaScript code can access the other document elements. So you can use them directly to share data.

Your first window w1 opens w2 and save the reference

```
var w2 = window.open(...)
```

In w2 you can access w1 using the opener property of `window`.

Comment: USING COOKIES? Eat them and enjoy! There is a MUCH easier way!
Just access a var of the other window. Got a value var in w1, access it from w2 whit window.opener.value !

Comment: Let's say that the user opens them all. Any similar solution in that case?

Comment: I think that you may open as many windows you want and use this solution. The reference to any new window must be registered somewhere. The reference to the parent window is always available. I don't see any limitation so far. @Fardinak

Comment: Just so everyone knows, this is answer is wrong, as @Ferdinak already tried to say. You don't have a reference to a tab the user opens.

Comment: @DDS: you are right, as an answer this is wrong, but it seems to be interesting, so I let it there. Using localStorage I think is the right solution.

Comment: Interesting is irrelevant. This is a Q&A site first and foremost. People come to this page to look for answers to the asker's question. If you want to share something interesting, you should consider writing a new wiki-style question.

Comment: a little bit different question, is it possible for the child window to call a method from parent window? by parent window I mean the one which created child window using `window.open`...

Comment: Marek: of course you can, using window.opener.methodName from the child.

Comment: Marek: of course you can, using window.opener.methodName from the child.

Comment: @Marek - It is possible but it's bad software design, doing so you are tightly coupling the two windows. A better way is to fire a specific EVENT in the parent passing any data along with that event object and then let the parent respond to that EVENT. You can fire EVENTs or Messages using the postMessage API and use a polyfill for earlier browsers however you will need a ref' to the window where you want to send the Event in the same way you need a ref' to the window if you invoke a function directly. This though doesn't help the original question so LocalStorage is a better mechanism.

Comment: @jonas.ninja IMO the question was not 100% clear on how the tabs are opened, so this is a perfectly valid answer even if it's not a universal one.

Comment: @Superole I'm slightly embarrassed that I wrote that. I must have been angry that day or something. My apologies.

Comment: Please not the you cannot access properties of the pop up if they are in different origin

Answer (score 15):

You can do this via the local storage API. Note that this works only between two tabs. You can't put both sender and receiver on the same page:

On the sender page:

```
localStorage.setItem("someKey", "someValue");
```

On the receiver page:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);

        function storageEventHandler(evt) {
            alert("storage event called key: " + evt.key);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I was going to use this method until I found out that the webbrowser control does not fire the "storage" event handler method.  Not sure why.  Bug perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Made my day. It didn't work with file:/// protocol but works with a valid domain. Another similar demo http://html5demos.com/storage-events

Comment: You don't need to wait for DOM readiness in order to access localStorage

Answer (score 15):

There is also an experimental technology called [`Broadcast Channel API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) that is designed specifically for communication between different browser contexts with same origin. You can post messages to and recieve messages from another browser context without having a reference to it:

```
var channel = new BroadcastChannel("foo");
channel.onmessage = function( e ) {
  // Process messages from other contexts.
};
// Send message to other listening contexts.
channel.postMessage({ value: 42, type: "bar"});
```

Obviously this is experiental technology and is not supported accross all browsers yet.

Comment: It's no longer experimental, even tho Edge might have not implemented it (it's marked `?` in MDN)

Comment: Edge has it now.

Answer (score 12):

Below window(w1) opens another window(w2). Any window can send/receive message to/from another window. So we should ideally verify that the message originated from the window(w2) we opened.

In w1

```
var w2 = window.open("abc.do");
window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    console.log(event.data);
});
```

In w2(abc.do)

```
window.opener.postMessage("Hi! I'm w2", "*");
```

Comment: Does it works on all browsers?

Comment: @StepanYakovenko support for browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Browser_Compatibility

Answer (score 10):

Communicating between different JavaScript execution context was supported even before HTML5 if the documents was of the same origin.

If not or you have no reference to the other `Window` object, then you could use the new **postMessage API** introduced with HTML5. I elaborated a bit on both approaches in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004442/writing-a-javascript-file-from-another-javascript/18004937#18004937).

Comment: postMessage API is not designed for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/1100416/470117 You need the reference of targeted window to post a message for that specific window

Answer (score 9):

You can communicate between windows (tabbed or not) if they have a child-parent relationship.

Create and update a child window:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cross window test script</title>
<script>
var i = 0;
function open_and_run() {
    var w2 = window.open("", "winCounter"); 
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer(w2)},1000);
}

function myTimer(w2) {
    i++;
    w2.document.body.innerHTML="<center><h1>" + i + "</h1><p></center>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Click to open a new window 
<button onclick="open_and_run();">Test This!</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

Child windows can use the `parent` object to communicate with the parent that spawned it, so you could control the music player from either window.

See it in action here: https://jsbin.com/cokipotajo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: One problem here is, that we can not (without being hacky) share a link to our synced view...

Comment: @yckart There are so many ways to do this but the most common way I've seen is to send the string to an input box in the other window. You can make an event listener for a change of value. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994120/javascript-pass-selected-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-window-input-box . I think it would be better to just call a javascript function in the other window, passing it the URL. E.g., <a href="javascript:window.parent.mySendURL(url)"> from the child window or <a href="javascript:myChildWindow.mySendURL(url)"> from the parent window.

Answer (score 2):

I found a different way using HTML5 localstorage. I've created a library with events like API:

```
sysend.on('foo', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {
    sysend.broadcast('foo', {message: input.value});
};
```

https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js

It will send messages to all other pages, but not to the current one.

**EDIT**:

The library in the newest version also supports broadcast channel communication, but still, it works in IE11 that only supports local Storage. It also supports cross-origin communication (different domains) but a little bit of code.

The latest API also supports the `emit` function that executes events also on the same page.

Even latest version, also suport managing the windows, send message to particular window or get list of widows/tabs.

Comment: Can you add a link to this library?

Comment: @DennisNerush https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js

Answer (score -1):

With Flash you can communicate between any window, *any* browser (yes, from Firefox to Internet Explorer at runtime) ...*any* form of instance of Flash ([Shockwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Shockwave) or [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX)).

Comment: Question was not about Flash.

Comment: This won't work in most mobile situations.

Comment: To be fair, Flash runs "a form of" Javascript just as the OP requested

Comment: How does it work? What is the mechanism? Wouldn't the browser prevent it from working? Does it go through some server on the Internet?

Comment: OK, he has left the building. Can somebody else chime it?