# How to control opener page which is opened by window.open method

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open, window.opener

I have a page in which i m calling another popup by window.open method. The only thing how can i change a label in opener page from popup page while the popup page is still alive ie which is not closed yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('label1').value = "the new value";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to let the opener window take care of changing values by exposing a small API to the popup window.

I've outlined it here: [javascript - pass selected value from popup window to parent window input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994120/javascript-pass-selected-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-window-input-box)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var additionalWindow = window.open("/additional");

    // Write on the additional window
    additionalWindow.document.write('written from separate window');

    // Call a function on the additional window
    additionalWindow.someFunction();
}
</script>
```

[Here's Mozilla's documentation on `window.open()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)