# Send data to separate window javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a new popup window from an existing page using:

```
window.open("myUrl","myName","width=200,height=200");
```

Now on that popup window I have a text input and a button, I want to create an onclick method for the button that sends the text inputs value to the page that created the popup without using a form or php, is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994120/javascript-pass-selected-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-window-input-box/10407064#10407064

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the **window.opener** keyword

lets say you have a javascript method doSomething(value){....} in your parent class, then from your POPUP you can call the parent function using

```
window.opener.doSomething("here is my data from child sent to parent");
```

**UPDATED**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both the parent and the new window are on the same domain, you should be able to directly manipulate their JS environment:

```
var w = window.open("myUrl", "myName", "width=200,height=200");
var e = w.document.getElementById('someId');
// do something with element e
```

If they are on different domains, you might need to use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) or other cross-domain messaging techniques, if window.postMessage is not supported by your targeted browsers.

Comment: Why? He wants to add a handler on an element in the created window, which does something in the parent window. This can be done in either direction.

Comment: But from child to parent the syntax is different - and it is triggered in child

Comment: Yes, but you can still accomplish it from parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

Any open window call forms a get request to new window. This is very simple way that you pass the params you want to send using URL itself like,

```
var myUrl = "http://example.com/test?myName=" + myName;
window.open(myUrl,"windowName","width=200,height=200");
```

Now on the page you can get myName as a request parameter. Please try this.