# Pass JSON from one html to other HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I am building a web application that's purely dependent on services. so, the client side code is purely html, javascript/jQuery which calls some REST services to render UI. i would need to pass a jSON object from one html page to other html page. The target html page will need to open in new window..

Is there an easy & efficient way to accomplish the same?

I am reading through backbone routers etc..., but was wondering if that's an overkill. please advice.

Few considerations:

need a cross browser (if not really old browsers) solution and can not pass as part of query string. as this will be quite big

Comment: Please post your code so far, it is not clear what you're asking exactly. Have you tried localstorage or cookies?

Comment: Have you considered a client side framework like Ember.js, Backbone.js or Angular?

Comment: I would try to use the way explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732065/send-data-to-seperate-window-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot pass as part of a query string, then you will need some sort of back end to your application. One suitable candidate would be Firebase (a back-end service that has free options). This is particular useful to you since your application seems to be front end heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just so the answer is clear:

```
// Your /main.html file
<script type="text/javascript">
    w = window.open("/other.html", "WindowTitle");

    function getJSON(){
        return my_json_data;
    }
</script>

// Your /other.html file
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get Json Data
   my_json_data = window.opener.getJSON();
</script>
```

Comment: works only if both pages are from same domain. If on same domain, window.postMessage looks like cleaner approach

Comment: uh never used that! Write an answer from it