# fetch the variable from php to javascript and use it

Tags: javascript, php

**THIS IS META.PHP . I AM JUST PASSING SESSION VALUE USING JAVA SCRIPT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./js/laddubox.js"></script>
<script src="./js/pop.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var page = "<?php echo $_SESSION['pa'] ?>";
</script>
<title><?=$title?></title>
</head>
```

**THIS IS A POP-UP IN JS . NOW I WANT THE SESSION VALUE IN THIS POP-UP AND I HAVE CREATED THE HIDDEN INPUT FIELD TO PASS THE VALUE TO ANOTHER PAGE**

```
function sin() {
    var lbox = new LadduBox();
    lbox.init({
        "width": 500,
        "height": 300,
        "HTML": '<div style="width:495px; height:272px; background-color:#ffffff; border:2px solid orange;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="485" height="270" style="font-family:arial; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;"><tr><td align="right" colspan="3"><img src="images/untitled-1.png" style="margin:10px; cursor:pointer;" id="btnClose"/></td></tr><tr><td height="30" colspan="3"><div style="font-family:arial; font-size:20px; color:#ff6c00; padding-left:200px;">SIGN IN</div></td></tr><tr><td><form method="get"><div style="margin:10px; font-size:14px;">EMAIL<br><input type="text" name="email"/></div><br><div style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:-10px; font-size:14px;">PASSWORD<br><input type="hidden" name="page" value=""/><input type="text" name="paswrd"/></div><br><input type="submit" value="submit"  class="subbg"/></form></td><td><img src="images/orbar.png" /></td><td align="center"><a href=sign_in.php?val=1"><img src="images/redfb.png" style="margin-bottom:7px;"/></a><br><a href=sign_in.php?val=2"><img src="images/redgoogle.png" style="margin-bottom:7px;"/></a><br><a href=sign_in.php?val=3"><img src="images/redtwitter.png" /></a></td></tr></table></div>',
        'btnCloseId': '#btnClose'
    });
    lbox.fire();
}
```

**SO PLEASE IF ANYONE KNOWS THE ANSWERE PLEASE HELP ME**

Comment: I would add quotes around your `echo` call, since those values are usually strings. `var page = "<?php echo $_SESSION['pa']; ?>"`. Everything else seems good.

Comment: in hidden set  value= '<?php echo $_SESSION['pa'] ?>'

Comment: @jrthib done after that wat will i do ??

Comment: @VinodLouis its not working

Comment: Did you call [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) ?

Comment: yes , Its showing me the value in input element .........the value i have passed in meta.php

Comment: It's related to open new window and send JS data to it I guess look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732065/send-data-to-seperate-window-javascript

Comment: @PHP_USER1 After you put quotes, the value from `$_SESSION['pa']` is set to page, you can just call page in your javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

You have this HTML snippet:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value=""/>
```

Just insert PHP value there as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pa'] ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as you are just missing the semicolon at the end of the php statement?
    var page = "";