# Javascript change class value of selection box

Tags: javascript

I have a popup window that I click values from and depending on the value I want to change the value of a selection box class value in the parent window.

I have the name of the selection element but don't know how to reference the class attrib ?

```
window.opener.document.getElementsByName('options[911]')
```

Any ideas

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript - pass selected value from popup window to parent window input box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994120/javascript-pass-selected-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-window-input-box)

Comment: In addition to answers below, I suggest you also investigate the `.classList` property object. It has a number of useful member functions to manipulate classes(`.add`, `.contains`, `.remove`, `.toggle`), rather than forcing you to do your own string operations on the single string found in `.className`.

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute means something else than the one you need. Use className

```
element.className
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/DOM/element.className

Answer (score 0):

Use `.className`

```
window.opener.document.getElementsByName('options[911]').className = 'new class';
```

The above is not so robust.

You'll need something like this:

```
var elem = window.opener.document.getElementsByName('options[911]');
elem.className = elem.className.replace('oldClass','newClass');
```