# PHP : how to trigger javascript function from a button in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[image]

I have 3 buttons.

1. **search button** : this will open popup page.
2. **add row button** : this will trigger a javascript function to add row.
3. **select button** : will trigger a javascript function to get row value and send it to main page.

**search** and **add row** buttons are in main page, and **select** button is on popup page.

i need **select** button to handle javascript function in main page, so i can remove add row button.

> to put it simple, my question is how i do trigger javascript function to add row
>   in main page, using select button in popup page?

if my question isn't clear please ask, thanks.

Comment: can use postMessage API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alhamdulillah finaly i got the answer to execute javascript function on parent window from popup window^^,

on parent window:

```
<html>
<head><title>MAIN WINDOW</title></head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function hello(){
   alert("Hello");
   }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and on popup window:

```
 <html>
    <head><title>POPUP WINDOW</title></head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" onClick="javascript:callHelloOnParent()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function callHelloOnParent(){
      window.opener.hello();
      return false;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a general example.

(parent window)

```
<html> 
<script language="javascript"> 
function openWindow() { 
  window.open("target.html","_blank","height=200,width=400, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"); 
} 
</script> 
<body> 
<form name=frm> 
<input id=text1 type=text> 
<input type=button onclick="javascript:openWindow()" value="Open window.."> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

(child window)

```
<html> 
<script language="javascript"> 
function changeParent() { 
  window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value="Value changed..";
  window.close();
} 
</script> 
<body> 
<form> 
<input type=button onclick="javascript:changeParent()" value="Change opener's textbox's value.."> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

http://www.codehappiness.com/post/access-parent-window-from-child-window-or-access-child-window-from-parent-window-using-javascript.aspx

More discussion: [javascript - pass selected value from popup window to parent window input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994120/javascript-pass-selected-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-window-input-box)

Comment: in my picture on above, i already able to send value to parent window. what i want is how to run javascript function in parent window from child window ^^