# Listening for new window form submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

On button click open new window, when the new window form is submitted and is successful it closes, needing to either refresh the main page or delete the button clicked.

Is there a way to add some form of event listener that can listen to the windows form submit success? The button can't be deleted if the user decides to just close the window.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('/new/window','_blank','width=800,height=600')">Fire new window</a>
```

I'm really stuck on this and can't think of way that it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this other Stackoverflow question might help you.

[Javascript communication between browser tabs/windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows)

A summary is that it uses cookies and a setTimeout to constantly check is a cookie has been changed in the cookie by the other window/tab.