# Can EventBus call a separated Presenter (not a nested Presenter) in GWTP?

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp, event-bus

Ok, here is my problem. I have 2 presenters: FirstPresenter (ex: abc.com#first) & SecondPresenter (ex: abc.com#second). There is a button on SecondPresenter & when user clicks on that button then the FirstPresenter will popup a message.

So, here is what I did, I used eClipse to create an event name MyEvent, the eclipse generated a class MyEvent.java

On the SecondPresenter, I got:

```
    private EventBus eventBus;

    @Inject
    public SecondPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view,
            final MyProxy proxy) {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy);
        this.eventBus=eventBus;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();
        passMsgButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                MyEvent myEvent =new MyEvent();
                myEvent.setMsg("hello");
                SecondPresenter.this.eventBus.fireEvent(myEvent);    
            }               
        });
    }
```

On the FirstPresenter, I got:

```
    private final MyHandler myHandler=new MyHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onMy(
                MyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Window.alert(event.getMsg());



        }}; 

    @Override
    protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();
        registerHandler(getEventBus().addHandler(MyEvent.getType(), myHandler));
    }
```

If the FirstPresenter is the nested presenter that is embedded inside the SecondPresenter then that above code works fine. But if they are 2 separated Presenters then the above code didn't work.

Why? I checked Google doc & they just say that EventBus can call a Presenter, they didn't say it must be the nested presenter so I assumed that EventBus can call any separated presenter.

I changed `private EventBus` to `public EventBus`, but it didn't help.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I changed my code a bit, it works partially. I am not sure i'm doing right thing since it still has some issues.

Ok, on the FirstPresenter I implements MyHandler & Override onMy method

```
   public class FirstPresenter extends
    Presenter<FirstPresenter.MyView, FirstPresenter.MyProxy> implements MyHandler{

  private final MyHandler myHandler=new MyHandler(){

    @Override
    public void onMy(
            MyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Window.alert(event.getMsg());
    }}; 

     @ProxyEvent

     @Override
      public void onMy(MyEvent event) {
        Window.alert(event.getMsg());
          getView().getHtmlPanel().add(new Label("test"));
      }
      @Override
      protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();
        registerHandler(getEventBus().addHandler(MyEvent.getType(), myHandler));
      }
    }
```

When I click the button on SecondPresenter (a page on a 2nd tab of Webbrowser) then I saw the message popup on the 2nd tab (i.e. the browser didn't make the 1st tab on focus), but when I click on the FirstPresenter (a page on 1st tab) I didn't see the `Label("test")`?

Why it can call the Window.alert but didn't add the Label onto the FirstPresenter?

Also, how can I get the Browser to set focus on the FirstPresenter (i.e. show the the first tab)?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you have two top level presenters only one is active at any time. 
I guess that the `onBind()` method of the `FirstPresenter` hasn't been called and thus the handler hasn't been attached to the `Event` on the `EventBus`.

It works with nested presenters because there both `Presenters` are "active" at the same time.

You have to rely on [ProxyEvent](http://arcbees.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/using-proxyevent/) to "wake up the `FirstPresenter`

Comment: hi Ümit, Thank you very much. i did as u said but It worked partially. I detailed in my answer, can you have a look to see whether I am missing something?

Comment: There is no way to do direct communication between different tabs in the browser. You have to rely on `Messages` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows)

Comment: thax u very much anyway