# Updating multiple tabs with KnockoutJS

Tags: user-interface, mvvm, knockout.js, tabs

My users browse products and add some of them to their baskets.
I use KnockoutJS to update the listing of the basket content.

However, users can open product links on multiple tabs/windows in the same session and pick one product on the first, another product on the second tab. *I'd like to display the same basket content on each page, of course.*

**Is KnockoutJS able to update the DOMs of different tabs simultaneously?**

I'd like a solution which updates the changes only, and immediately as KnockoutJS does on a single page. I was mentioning a basket to illustrate the problem, but a basket's content is relatively small and could be retrieved by an AJAX call easily when the user brings up a background tab. *The real problem is different views of a huge database, which can be updated in multiple tabs and should look consistent on every tab.* It takes several seconds to build up the DOM of a tab.

(This question is NOT about jQuery UI Tabs. The situation is as described in http://thesocialtester.co.uk/20-days-of-web-testing-multiple-tabs-and-windows/)

If the answer is *not possible*, I'd like to hear about workarounds or good practices.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout does not address the underlying **general problem** of communicating across browser tabs with javascript. There are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-communication-between-tabs-windows-with-same-origin/12514384#12514384) on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows), and the same solutions will be usable with whatever framework you pick.

But no, Knockout makes no attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the accepted answer, Knockout does not solve the cross-tab problem.

If your problem is strictly confined to the case of synching several tabs in the same browser, then using localStorage to pass messages (as described in [this answer cited in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514384/1077987) seems like a sane solution.

The question is whether you don't really want to go further in solving this problem, and implement some form of server push to your shopping page, which would then also work cross-browser and cross-machine.

In this case, you'd want some solution which uses WebSocket (real server push to the client), possibly combined with a HTTP polling fallback for older browsers (if you need to support those).