# How to fill another website's form with the data in my own website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Here is the thing, I have a form in my web site looks like something like this:

Name: ----

Last name: ----

.

.

.

something like this, I work with a site that I have to send this information and type this requests again in that site with the same fields.

It means I want to copy my forms data to the target website's form with the same fields.

I do not have the access to target website's codes and I'm just a user there.

So I want to know if there is a way using Jquery, javascript or anything help me make a button that When I click that the data copy from my site to the target website.

Is it possible to access another browser's page tab inside another one??!! with jqyery?

Thank you in advance

Comment: _I do not have the access to target website's codes and I'm just a user there._ No.

Comment: You can use cURL...!!! Please refer https://php.net/curl

Comment: HI , Nice question , it seems not possible or feasible at first , but one possibility is there if that website uses $_GET to fill it forms , so you can do this upto some extent

Comment: Maybe I am totally off here but such a copy command should rather be provided by a browser plugin that copies the values among the currently opened tabs.

Comment: Would you like a demo addon Masoud? for firefox which copies the first name and last name text fields?

Comment: Is there any add on for that @Noit

Comment: yeah check out Saved Password Editor. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saved-password-editor/

Comment: after downloading, click in the form on your site and then click "create login info". just a demo to show you a way to remember stuff.

Comment: actually is a better addon, it does exactly what you need: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried your problem, and this is just an opinion.

If that website is using a get() method, you are saved. You can form a query string in the same format and execute it, else if you are trying to do something like that automatically if there is some captcha check you may fail, and the server will be blocking you thinking it's a DOS attack.

And this is something which may be helpful to you.
[Javascript communication between browser tabs/windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows)

Answer (score 0):

```
var w2 = window.open("Website you need to fill the form");
```

Now use `w2` as owner window, in order to access the elements.