# Change content of a div on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page 1, I have a `div` containing information.

```
<div id='information'></div>
```

And on page 2, I have a `form` with a `textarea` and a button.

```
<form>
  <textarea id='new-info'></textarea>
  <input type='submit' id='submit-info' value='pass'/>
</form>
```

Now what I want is when I click the submit button, the text inputted in the text area will be posted in `div#information` changing its previous content.
I have seen many other post on how to change div content, but those were unrelated to my problem.

Comment: The easiest would be to use PHP and change content via `GET` or `POST` values, I believe.

Comment: Are the pages open at the same time? Then this can only be done if one of the pages has been opened by the other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript communication between browser tabs/windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows)

Comment: @DanielLisik, how can I use `POST` here? can you show me some samples?

@flec no. the page aren't open at the same time.

thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Nixxhalle does the user gets redirected to the second page or are they in two iframes?

Comment: @still_learning, i need the inserted data to be permanent until the user submit again new information on the div. Thus, the link you give is the same? thought if i clean the browsing history it will vanished cause it is transferred through cookies.. Thanks  a lot

Comment: @DanielLisik yes, they are in two different iframes.

Comment: @Nixxhalle if you want to, you could do like this: Send the form to a PHP page where it saves the data in a DB, and have the second page checking with an interval after data, that way the new information will be permanent until overwritten by new one.

Comment: @Nixxhalle So you want two windows which are not open at the same time to communicate in a way that cannot be interrupted by clearing the browser history / cookies?

Comment: @DanielLisik, i was thinking about that. but still i tried if there's some more methods i can try. Do you think it's the best way for my problem?

Comment: @still_learning, yes. That's what i want.

Comment: @Nixxhalle I would say it's a very good solution, yes. Should I post an answer with that method?

Comment: if you could. I would gladly accept your answer.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will give you an idea of how you can do it:

## Page 2

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <textarea id='new-info'></textarea>
  <input type='submit' id='submit-info' value='pass'/>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$("form").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('save_data.php', { new_info:$("#new-info").val() }).done(function(data){
         // Do something if you want to show that form has been sent
    });


});
```

**save_data.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['new-info'])) {

    // Update value in DB

}


?>
```

## Page 1

**HTML**

```
<div id='information'>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
setInterval(search_after_info, 1000);


function search_after_info() {

    $.get('get_data', function(data) {

        $("#information").html(data);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to do like what the other answers mentioned, to have each tab communicate to a central server that will get/send data to keep both tabs updated using AJAX for example.

But I'm here to tell you about another way though, it's to use what we already have designed for this kind of task exactly. What so called browser **`localStorage`**

Browser storage works like this pseudo code:

```
  //set the value, it works as a hash map or assoc array. 
   localStorage .setItem("some_index_key", "some data") ; 
   // get the value by it's index key. 
   localStorage .getItem("some_index_key") ; // will get you "some data"
```

Where all the data will be shared among all open tabs for the same domain. And you can add event listener so whenever one value change, it will be reflected on all tabs.

```
addEvent(window, 'storage', function (event) {
  if (event.key == 'some_index_key') {
    output.innerHTML = event.newValue;
  }
});

addEvent(myInputField, 'keyup', function () {
  localStorage.setItem('some_index_key', this.value);
});
```

**Check out this [DEMO](http://html5demos.com/storage-events), you edit one field on page-A, and that value will be reflected on page-B offline without the need to burden the network.**

To learn more, [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

**Real live example. The background color is controlled from another tab.**

```js
     var screenone = document.getElementById('screenone');

            screenone.addEventListener('keydown', screenOneFunction);
            screenone.addEventListener('change', screenOneFunction);
           
    function screenOneFunction()
            {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
                localStorage.setItem("color1", this.value);
            }
            
            
            
            var screentwo = document.getElementById('screentwo');

            screentwo.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
                localStorage.setItem("color2", this.value);
            });
            screentwo.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
                localStorage.setItem("color2", this.value);
            });



            var thebutton = document.getElementById('thebutton');

            thebutton.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                localStorage.clear();
                screenone.value = "";
                screentwo.value = "";
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "";
            });



            var storageHandler = function () {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.color2;
                var color1 = localStorage.color1;
                var color2 = localStorage.color2;
                screenone.value = color2;
                screentwo.value = color1;

            };
            window.addEventListener("storage", storageHandler, false);
```

```css
       .screenone{ border: 1px solid black;}
       input{ margin: 10px; width: 250px; height: 20px; border:round}
      label{margin: 15px;}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <label> Type a color name e.g. red. Or enter a color hex code e.g. #001122 </label>
        <br>
        <input type="text"   class="screenone" id="screenone" /> 
        <label> This tab </label> 
        <br>
        <input type="text"   class="screentwo" id="screentwo" /> 
        <label> Other opned tabs </label>  
        <br>
        <input type="button"   class=" " id="thebutton" value="clear" /> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mike

window.addEventListener("storage", storageHandler, false);

Comment: @Mike hey, I made a full example. Check my edited answer. Put the code in an html file and try to run. You will be able to change the background color of all opened tabs from any tab!

Answer (score 0):

You mean some thing like this ?

```
$("#submit-info").click(function() {
   var content = $("#new-info").text();
   $("#information").html(content);
  });
```

If you thing about server side, tell more about technology, which you use.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly as the following:
Page 1:

```
<form action="test2.htm" method="get">
<textarea name ='new-info'></textarea>
<input type = 'submit' id='submit-info' value ='pass'  onclick="postData();"/>
```

Page 2

```
   <div id="information"></div>
<script> 
        if (location.search != "")
        {
            var x = location.search.substr(1).split(";")
            for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
            {
                var y = x[i].split("=");
                var DataValue = y[1];
                document.getElementById("information").innerHTML  = DataValue;
            }
        }       


</script>
```