# A "simple" button script in HTML

Tags: html

I want a script with a button that swaps text on another page(website)

so its a maintenance button when pressed on the administrator page it make text appear on the home page

what I've got

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Welcome!") {
    x.innerHTML = "Sorry but this site is under Planed maintenance!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Welcome!";
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button></p>

<div id="myDIV">Welcome!</div>
```

Comment: Your code works as expected. You want this code to access another website and change text there? That is only possible if you can read the other website on the server or by using CORS and AJAX

Comment: Is the page part of the website?

Comment: Yes the page is part of the website!

Comment: This won't work with pure javascript. You need to persist the "maintenance" value somewhere on the server.

Comment: Ok How do i do that

Comment: this maybe help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809815/change-content-of-a-div-on-another-page