# Reload a particular domain's Tabs in Browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET Web application and different pages are opened in **multiple tabs** of **same browser**.

Now, if user logs through a **new tab** in the **same browser**, I want to refresh all the tabs of that **particular domain/website**, which are already opened in different tabs of same browser.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks..!!

Comment: Use AJAX to render other tabs partially. To load other tabs asynchronously you can use [ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel Triggers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers), other option with jQuery or plain JavaScript ajax.

Comment: @VenkataPanga, I am talking about Browser Tabs..

Comment: That. Or you can try using cookies to communicate between tabs. Check every second to see if a cookie exists. If it does, force refresh.
See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows

Comment: Oops! My apologies please ignore my statement

Comment: In addition to  @miro 's great cookie suggestion you can use [localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-communication-between-tabs-windows-with-same-origin/12514384#12514384) concept as well