# How I Can Pause All Playing Audio On All Opening Pages Using Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, razor, html5-audio

how i can pause all playing audio on all opening pages when I play the new audio on new tab
I want audio playing way as The way on "soundcloud.com"
Thank you
I am using this player

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I have page for album it's Include Multiple player, I pause all player's in album page by this code

```
Pu = function ()
{
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
    {
        var item = lis[i];
        item.pause();
    }
}
```

but I need a code to pause all players in the all open page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate between pages you should use **cookies**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079423/1849444) is an example how to do it.