# How to update a text in a new opened window through JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am calling the following function from a button click to open a new window/tab and display an alert and update a text:

```
function nWin(p) {
    var setStyle = "<style rel='stylesheet'>\
        .vTop {\
            vertical-align: top;\
        }\
        <\/style>";
    var setScript = "<script>alert('test');<\/script>";
    setScript += "<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'><\/script>";
    setScript += "<script>$(function () { $('#sText').html('UPDATED TEST'); });<\/script>";
    var w = window.open();
    var createBody = $(w.document.body);
    var createHead = $(w.document.head);
    createBody.html("");
    createBody.html(p);
    createBody.append("<span id='sText'>THIS IS A TEST</span>");
    createHead.html(setStyle);
    createHead.append(setScript);
}
```

When I click the button the alert is shown from the page I click the button from rather than on the window/tab that is created and also the `sText` text does not change.

Here is a HTML Source:

[image]

How can I resolve it so it works correctly, where the alert is shown in the new window/tab and also the span text is updated.

Comment: use `postMessage` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript communication between browser tabs/windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows)

Comment: Not actually a duplicate of the `postMessage` question as the issue is writing to a new **sourceless** window's DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your approach to adding content to the new window. The following works;

```
function nWin(p) {
    var setStyle = "<style rel='stylesheet'>\
        .vTop {\
            vertical-align: top;\
        }\
        <\/style>";
    var setScript = "<script>alert('test');<\/script>";
    setScript += "<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'><\/script>";
    setScript += "<script>(function () { $('#sText').html('UPDATED TEST'); })();<\/script>";
    var w = window.open();
    w.document.write('<head>');
    w.document.write(setStyle);
    w.document.write('</head><body>');
    w.document.write("<span id='sText'>THIS IS A TEST</span>");
    w.document.write(setScript);
    w.document.write('</body>');
 }
```

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/hcdfr7sb)

Comment: So dont worry about the body or head section?

Comment: Right. Although, just to be safe from browser difference, you can write in the <head>...</head><body>...</body>. I modified the answer and Fiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function doSomeThing(){
   alert('test');
   setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'sText\').innerHTML=\"UPDATED TEST\"',500);
   document.getElementById('sText').innerHTML="UPDATED TEST";
  }

function nWin(p) {
    var setStyle = "<style rel='stylesheet'>\
        .vTop {\
            vertical-align: top;\
        }\
        <\/style>";

    var w = window.open();
    var createBody = $(w.document.body);
    var createHead = $(w.document.head);
    createHead.html(setStyle);

    var script = w.document.createElement('script');
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('('+ doSomeThing+')();'));
    (w.document.body || w.document.head || w.document.documentElement).appendChild(script);

    createBody.html("");
    createBody.html(p);
    createBody.append("<span id='sText'>THIS IS A TEST</span>");

   }
```