# Reloading a browser tab when another is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, reload

I have a web application that displays visuals based on user input. So I have a browser tab for the visuals and one for the user input. Is there a way to automatically reload the visuals tab whenever the user finishes inputting information in the other tab? Does javascript have anything for that kind of configuration?

I tried to look here but didn't find anything similar.

Thank you.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows

Comment: Both tabs need to access some common storage medium. That means cookie, local storage, server-side database or server-side file system. Server-side session is also a possibility but with constraints.