# How to fire a jquery function from another page without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, paypal

I have following paypal button in one of the page but at the start, its hidden.
lets say page1.php

```
                <div id="over" style="display:none;">
                <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="'.$webinar_paypal_link.'">
                <input type="hidden" name="custom_name" value="'.$post_id.'">
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" id="notify_url" value="ipn_get.php?action=ipn">
                <input type="image" class="paypalbutton" src="" border="0" name="submit" alt="JOIN OUR SUCCESS TEAM NOW">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>                         
                    </div>
```

And in the admin, i have a interface where admin can choose whether to display button yes or no and information is stored in database.
So at that time, when admin choose yes, i want to show paypal button on page1.php (means change style="display:block from style="display:none;") without page refresh.

IS that possible?

Comment: If you want to show or disable the button in "real-time", there must be some kind of comunication. Either polling from the server every X seconds or making some kind of persistent connection maybe using [WAMP Proto](http://wamp-proto.org/).

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez i dont want to pull the server every x seconds it can increase a load on server resources. is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do with jQuery alone, client-side (no requests to the server). It is possible using [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

Is it worth the complexity in your case? Probably not. I would advise just [polling the server client-side](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) for updates. The addition in load will likely be negligible unless your application can't handle simple GET requests and has many, many concurrent users.

Edit: I'm wrong. [You can use cookies for this purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079423/1601317). But I don't think it's worth it when comparing that technique to using a well-known pattern like polling the server.