# Event listener across tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have two windows: window A and window B.

window A and window B are active on the same Web-browser.

window A contains a script.

**Questions:**

Is it possible for window A to listen to events that are happening in windows B such as `keyup`?

Please provide some explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure about `keyup` in question, but there are some events possible, like focus iirc.

Answer (score 1):

In window B you set a cookie and in window A you create a setTimeout function that every "x" milliseconds check if there are any new cookie.

Look at this: [Javascript communication between browser tabs/windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows)

Comment: That's a pretty messy solution, but I like it! What else is JavaScript for than messy solutions, right?

Comment: Consider `window`'s storage event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Answer (score 0):

If window A is a parent of window B (A opened B) then it's possible to find the element and add event listener. Also you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communticate between windows.

Answer (score 0):

Window A can listen to Window B events using sockets, checkout socket.io library.
Where we need to emit an event and listen across all windows or specific windows can be possible using this library.